# Scikit SVM error: X.shape[1] = 1 should be equal to 2

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I am trying to use Scikit to train 2 features called: x1 and x2. Both these arrays are shape `(490,1)`. In order to pass in one `X` argument into `clf.fit(X,y)`, I used `np.concatenate` to produce an array shape `(490,2)`. The label array is composed of 1's and 0's and is shape `(490,)`. The code is shown below:

```
x1 = int_x # previously defined array shape (490,1)
x2 = int_x2 # previously defined array shape (490,1)
y=np.ravel(close) # where close is composed of 1's and 0's shape (490,1)
X,y = np.concatenate((x1[:-1],x2[:-1]),axis=1), y[:-1] #train on all datapoints except last 
clf = SVC()
clf.fit(X,y)
```

The following error is shown:

```
X.shape[1] = 1 should be equal to 2, the number of features at training time
```

What I don't understand is why this message appears even though when I check the shape of X, it is indeed 2 and not 1. I originally tried this with only one feature and `clf.fit(X,y)` worked well, so I am inclined to think that `np.concatenate` produced something that was not suitable. Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say without having the concrete values of `int_x`, `int_x2` and `close`. Indeed, if I try with `int_x`, `int_x2` and `close` randomly constructed as

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVC

int_x = np.random.normal(size=(490,1))
int_x2 = np.random.normal(size=(490,1))
close = np.random.randint(2, size=(490,))
```

which conforms to your specs, then your code works. Thus the error may be in the way you constructed int_x, int_x2 and close.

If you believe the problem is not there, could you please share a minimal reproducible example with specific values of `int_x`, `int_x2` and `close`?

Comment: I just tried it using the same method you did above but received the same error. Can you provide the rest of your code that produced a successful result from above?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what was wrong with my code.

First, I should have created another variable, say `x` that defined the concatenation of `int_x` and `int_x2` and is shape: (490,2), which is the same shape as `close`. This came in handy later.

Next, the `clf.fit(X,y)` was not incorrect in itself. However, I did not correctly formulate my prediction code. For instance, I said: `clf.predict([close[-1]])` in hopes of capturing the binary target output (either 0 or 1). The argument that was passed into this method was incorrect. It should have been `clf.predict([x[-1]])` because the algorithm predicts the label at the feature location as opposed to the other way around. Since the variable `x` is now the same shape as `close`, then the result of `clf.predict([x[-1]])` should produce the predicted result of `close[-1]`.